# Using <link> where 'rel' is not 'stylesheet'

Tags: html

Under what circumstances might one use a `<link>` element where `rel` is something *other* than `stylesheet`?  HTML5 supports quite a few other `rel` values on `link` elements, including

- `archives`
- `author`
- `first`, `last`, `next`, `prev`
- `help`
- `index`, `up`
- More at listed at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types.

But `link` elements go in the `head` section; they don't correspond to page contents.  What then is the point of linking to a bunch of semantically-interesting documents if the user has no way of opening the link?

Answer (score 3):

Historically, some web browsers exposed "structural" `rel` links, such as "first", "prev", "next", "last", *etc*. in the user interface. For instance, [some early versions of the iCab browser displayed buttons in the toolbar for these links](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/icab-new-browser-structural-navigation/).

Nowadays, though, they're essentially unused by web browsers. I'm not aware of any common use for them. Indeed, there's no clear use for them in many modern web applications. (There's no obvious "next" page from this question on Stack Overflow, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

Like many other tags in the `head` section, `link` provides contextual information that is often more directly useful to browsers, bots, and search engines than end users.  For example, until 2014, Google allowed you to link a listing to your Google+ profile using the `rel=author` attribute.  In those cases, it just more context for the system to work with.

However, as a result, the end user should ultimately get more contextually appropriate, organized, and structured content, or in some cases, meta-content that just doesn't fit anywhere else (like the page's favicon or links to archived content).